# Azure Data Factory 2, Data flow with derived column, how to set a timestamp to null

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a Azure DataFactory V2 pipeline that executes a data flow.

The Azure Sql source table have a Date not null column, DateReported.
This is imported from an external source. Where null values are
1899-01-01.

The destination Sql table have the same field, DateReported but as Date null

I'm using a Derived Column in my dataflow to sanitize data.
I want to insert null when the date is 1899-01-01

My derived column function is this

```
iif(!(year(DateReported) == 1899 || year(DateReported) == 1753)
    , DateReported
    , null()
    )
```

This give me the error "Expression should return the same type 'timestamp' as previous expressions".

If I invert the iif to this

```
iif((year(DateReported) == 1899 || year(DateReported) == 1753)
    , null()
    , DateReported
    )
```

I get the error "Expression should return the same type 'null' as previous expressions"

I can fix this in sql from the source like this

```
Select ...
DateReported2 =
CASE
    WHEN DateReported is null THEN DateReported
    WHEN YEAR(DateReported) = 1899 THEN NULL
    ELSE DateReported
End
...
```

But this is messy, as all my other logic are in the dataflow.

How can I create a derived column that is a nullable timestamp, like C# DateTime? or SSIS NULL(DT_DATE)?

Solution:

```
case(year(DateReported) != 1899, DateReported)
```

Comment: Solid solution. I hope you won't mind, I've added your solution to my ADF Data Flows expression cheatsheet: https://aka.ms/dataflowexpsamples

Comment: hi,if you already solved your issue,you could summarize your solution as answer to end this case. It's really appreciate for your share.

Comment: @MarkKromer Please do feel free to use my solution.

Comment: @JayGong. The solution are found in the bottom of the post. Updated the post to clarify this.

Comment: Thanks! Added it to my ADF Data Flows expressions cheatsheet: https://github.com/kromerm/adfdataflowdocs/blob/master/data-flow-expression-samples.md