# Azure Data Factory 2, Data flow with derived nullable boolean column, how to set a boolean to null

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a source csv file like this

```
ID, IsEnabled
1,Y,
2,N,
3,,
```

And I'd like my destination csv file to look like this

```
ID, IsEnabled
1,TRUE,
2,FALSE,
3,,
```

In order to eventually map the IsEnabled column to a nullable bit in sql.

I've tried this expression without luck (From here: [Solved - Azure Data Factory 2, Data flow with derived column, how to set a timestamp to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57870594/solved-azure-data-factory-2-data-flow-with-derived-column-how-to-set-a-times))

```
case(IsEnabled=="N", false(), case(IsEnabled=="Y", true()))
```

I've also tried defining the default format to "Y" and "N" with and without the quotes with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the return of null() and cast the argument: toBoolean(toString(null()))

Comment: Couldn't get that to work - I tried the following when setting IsEnabled in the schema to both Boolean and String iif(IsEnabled== "Y", true(), iif(IsEnabled== "N", false(), toBoolean(toString(null()))))

Comment: What did end up working though was setting IsEnabled to string and doing the following: iif(IsEnabled == "Y", "TRUE", iif(IsEnabled == "N", "FALSE", "")). Can't say I love it, but it works

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a tranformation for IsEnabled as such

```
iif(IsEnabled == "Y", "TRUE", iif(IsEnabled  == "N", "FALSE", ""))
```

I also had to

1. Import the schema for the csv file
2. Set IsEnabled to string

Comment: empty string "" is not the same as null

Comment: @MarkKromerMSFT totally, I don't like this solution either, but it did import to sql into a nullable bit correctly. Would love a better solution.

Comment: Did you get a SQL error returned when you tried to write a null value into the bool column?

Comment: No, but that's likely because I did not provide a schema for the source csv to the destination table so it took the "" to be null. I would have loved to use the "define the default" functionality and use  "Y" and "N" to treat anything but Y and N as null - or something to that effect.